# Dynamically created array by html objects - asynchronous

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, asynchronous

I need to output an array of html objects. My function which handles output works asynchronously. I understand in async programming it can be that the last element is showed only of the loop.

My tries was a wrapping the code into other closures but it outputs nothing.

```
let run = () => {
  let array1 = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
    let children1 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < coordinate.length; k++) {
        let kk = k;
        setTimeout(function () {
          if (i === coordinate[kk].x && j === coordinate[kk].y) {
            children1.push(<Pool key={`${i}${j}`} row={`${square2}`}/>);
          }
          else if(i===packageCoordinate.x && j===packageCoordinate.y){
            children1.push(<Pool key={`${i}${j}`} row={`${square3}`}/>);
          }
          else{
            children1.push(<Pool key={`${i}${j}`} row={`${square1}`}/>);
          }
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
    array1.push(<div key={`${j}`}>{children1}</div>);
  }
};
```

In my opinion if else statemens aren't invoked properly.

EDIT:
I want to make if statement dynamically but k is always 0. And the secound issue I am getting error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0

```
 export default class Board extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    let array=[];
    for(let j=0;j<20;j++){
        let children=[];
        for(let i=0;i<20;i++){
            children.push(<Pool key={`${i}${j}`} row={`${square1}`}/>);
        }   
    array.push(<div key={`${j}`}>{children}</div>);     
    }
    this.state = {mainArray: array, indexArray: []}; 
}

renderMainArray(){
    return this.state.mainArray;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
stop = () => {
    alert("GAME OVER");
    window.location.reload("index.html");
}
run = () => {   
        let help="";
        let array1=[];
        for(let j=0;j<20;j++){

            let children1=[];
            for(let i=0;i<20;i++){                  
                help="";
                console.log(j);
                for(let k=0;k<coordinate.length;k++){
                    help+="coordinate[k].x===i && coordinate[k].y===j ";

                    if(k!==coordinate.length-1){
                        help+="||";
                    }
                }   

                    if(JSON.parse(help)){
                        children1.push(<Pool key={`${i}${j}`} row={`${square2}`}/>);
                    }   
                    else if(i===packageCoordinate.x && j===packageCoordinate.y){
                        children1.push(<Pool key={`${i}${j}`} row={`${square3}`}/>);
                    }
                    else{
                        children1.push(<Pool key={`${i}${j}`} row={`${square1}`}/>);
                    }
                }
            array1.push(<div key={`${j}`}>{children1}</div>);
            }   


        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        console.log(help);
        if(up===true){
        let help=Object.assign(coordinate[coordinate.length-1]);
            for(let i=0;i<=coordinate.length-2;++i){
                coordinate[i]=Object.assign({}, coordinate[i+1]);
            }
        help.x--;
        coordinate[coordinate.length-1]=Object.assign({}, help);
        }

        if(down===true){
        let help=Object.assign(coordinate[coordinate.length-1]);
            for(let i=0;i<=coordinate.length-2;++i){
                coordinate[i]=Object.assign({}, coordinate[i+1]);
            }
        help.x++;
        coordinate[coordinate.length-1]=Object.assign({}, help);

        }

        if(right===true){
        let help=Object.assign(coordinate[coordinate.length-1]);
            for(let i=0;i<=coordinate.length-2;++i){
                coordinate[i]=Object.assign({}, coordinate[i+1]);
            }
        help.y++;
        coordinate[coordinate.length-1]=Object.assign({}, help);
        }

        if(left===true){
            let help=Object.assign(coordinate[coordinate.length-1]);
            for(let i=0;i<=coordinate.length-2;++i){
                coordinate[i]=Object.assign({}, coordinate[i+1]);
            }
        help.y--;
        coordinate[coordinate.length-1]=Object.assign({}, help);
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if(coordinate[coordinate.length-1].x>20 || coordinate[coordinate.length-1].x<(-1) || coordinate[coordinate.length-1].y>20 || coordinate[coordinate.length-1].y<(-1) ){
            this.stop();
        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        this.setState({mainArray: array1});

    }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////


render() {
    return (        
        <div  className="main"> 
        {this.renderMainArray()}
        <button onClick={() => {setInterval(this.run, 1000);}}>Start the game!</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: you are pushing on `array1` before the `setTimeout` callback is called. Even more, all your loops will have done all iterations before any of those `setTimeout` callbacks are executed.

Comment: Maybe you could explain why you have those `setTimeout` calls and what you expect from them.

Comment: So I need it in the first loop?or in the first and secound?

Comment: run is invoked asynchronously. Every run outputs pools(Snake mini game).Pools are implemented in proper way because before starting game button all is outputed porperly

Comment: It depends on what you want. If all you want is to have things execute later, then put *all* of that code in one `setTimeout` callback: `let run = () => setTimeout(function () { .....`.

Comment: Yes it is done when the button is triggered - exactly this way "let run = () => setTimeout(function () { ....."

Comment: So, then you should not have to use any other call to `setTimeout`. Remove that from your inner loop.

Comment: an error occures somewhere in this code below

Comment: That is the most vague statement I have read today ;)

Comment: Tried. k value in simple loop is not the value expected.Most the time k is the last element element in every iteration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196277/discussion-between-trincot-and-tekblade).

Comment: What does this have to do with react? the code you're showing is very clearly not following the normal react lifecycle and state/props conventions, so I'm half tempted to say that whatever it is you're doing, this is probably doing that wrong. (At the very least, your code should be updating base data, then using `setState` to bind that new data, and have `render` automatically generate whatever it needs to based on that data change)

Comment: I added more code.

Comment: Why loops shows in console.log(i) ,console.log(j), console.log(k) always shows 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified and it works proper way. I've modified a way an inner loop is iterating - by JSON.parse and JSON.stringify

```
run = () => {   
        let help="";
        let array1=[];
        for(let j=0;j<20;j++){

            let children1=[];
            for(let i=0;i<20;i++){                  
                help="";
                let jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(coordinate));  //HERE
                for(let k=0;k<jsonData.length;k++){   /////HERE
                    let myObject = jsonData[k];       /////////////AND HERE
                    help+=`${myObject.x}===${i} && ${myObject.y}===${j} `;
                    if(k!==(jsonData.length-1)){
                        help+="||"
                    }
                }
                    if(eval(help)){
                        children1.push(<Pool key={`${i}${j}`} row={`${square2}`}/>);
                    }   
                    else if(i===packageCoordinate.x && j===packageCoordinate.y){
                        children1.push(<Pool key={`${i}${j}`} row={`${square3}`}/>);
                    }
                    else{
                        children1.push(<Pool key={`${i}${j}`} row={`${square1}`}/>);
                    }


            }
            array1.push(<div key={`${j}`}>{children1}</div>);
        }   


        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        console.log(help);
        if(up===true){
        let help=Object.assign(coordinate[coordinate.length-1]);
            for(let i=0;i<=coordinate.length-2;++i){
                coordinate[i]=Object.assign({}, coordinate[i+1]);
            }
        help.x--;
        coordinate[coordinate.length-1]=Object.assign({}, help);
        }

        if(down===true){
        let help=Object.assign(coordinate[coordinate.length-1]);
            for(let i=0;i<=coordinate.length-2;++i){
                coordinate[i]=Object.assign({}, coordinate[i+1]);
            }
        help.x++;
        coordinate[coordinate.length-1]=Object.assign({}, help);

        }

        if(right===true){
        let help=Object.assign(coordinate[coordinate.length-1]);
            for(let i=0;i<=coordinate.length-2;++i){
                coordinate[i]=Object.assign({}, coordinate[i+1]);
            }
        help.y++;
        coordinate[coordinate.length-1]=Object.assign({}, help);
        }

        if(left===true){
            let help=Object.assign(coordinate[coordinate.length-1]);
            for(let i=0;i<=coordinate.length-2;++i){
                coordinate[i]=Object.assign({}, coordinate[i+1]);
            }
        help.y--;
        coordinate[coordinate.length-1]=Object.assign({}, help);
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if(coordinate[coordinate.length-1].x>20 || coordinate[coordinate.length-1].x<(-1) || coordinate[coordinate.length-1].y>20 || coordinate[coordinate.length-1].y<(-1) ){
            this.stop();
        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        this.setState({mainArray: array1});

    }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////


render() {
    return (        
        <div  className="main"> 
        {this.renderMainArray()}
        <button onClick={() => {setInterval(this.run, 400);}}>Start the game!</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```